# Copy,Find,Selectall Functions in webbrowser of SWT application

Tags: java, browser, swt

I am developing an application in java using SWT.I have embeded a browser in the application taking help from the code snippets given in eclipse website.I have added a menubar with options like print,exit,help,copy,selectall and find.I have added functionality to print,exit and help and now i need to add functionality to copy,selectall and find buttons.I have searched for any such tutorials but in vain.Can anyone please help.I am using simple browser class only to implement the browser,if there are any other ways to embed a browser in my application to achieve all the functions please let me know.

Comment: You can use `Browser.execute` to run run JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: Is there no other way than using JavaScript?

Comment: @greg-449 can you give me the script to execute the copy function.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a Javascript expert

Comment: Well, there is an [answer for the search functionality here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17766507/1740724).